# How to declare inline object with inline variables in a single row for VS.NET

Tags: visual-studio

I want to declare an object in VS.NET with a couple of variables (properties) in it, in order to create a list of that object. I know that creating a class with the required properties will work, but there is a way to do it in a single method?

```
    Dim person As Object = New Object() {Name = "", Lastname = ""}

    Dim myList As New List(Of person)
    myList.Add(New person(Name = "x", LastName = "x1"))
```

Or maybe to resolve my main problem, if you know a way to create a kind of Hashtable or Dictionary that allows repeated keys would be great.

Thanks a lot for your help.

UPDATED
Note: I can't use LINQ

Comment: Do you need the object to be any specific type?  Could you use a LINQ query to produce a dynamic type from a XML string?

Comment: Would be a good idea, btw, to ask one question per question.

Comment: You are right Reed Copsey, sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know that creating a class with the required properties will work, but there is a way to do it in a single method

You can use [Collection Initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293617.aspxn) to initialize this in one "line" -

```
Dim myList As New List(Of Person) From { New Person(Name = "x", LastName = "x1") }
```

> Or maybe to resolve my main problem, if you know a way to create a kind of Hashtable or Dictionary that allows repeated keys would be great.

This is often done by making a Dictionary where the value is a collection, ie:

```
Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String))
```

This would let you create a dictionary where each String key could contain multiple string values.